# How to get Public IP of a LBaaS in Public Cloud?

Tags: kubernetes, ibm-cloud

We have deployed Docker Containers in Kubernetes Cluster in IBM CLoud.

We need a Load Balancer for the Cluster.

Created one Load Balancer (Public-->Private)

```
lb1   -   lb1-1890873-dal09.clb.appdomain.cloud. -  Public to Private -  Dallas 9. -  Online
```

We need to Supply this to Kubernetes Cluster Services.

Answer (score 0):

Broad question. I would just read [this documentation](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/containers?topic=containers-cs_network_planning). What type of load balancer do you want to use? LoadBalancer (Classic - NLB)? LoadBalancer (VPC load balancer) Ingress?

Answer (score 0):

If you have created a classic NLB, run the below command

```
ibmcloud ks nlb-dns add --cluster <cluster> --ip <load_balancer_IP> --nlb-host <Ingress_subdomain>
```

Check **step 6** in the [documentation here](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/containers?topic=containers-ingress-user_managed#user_managed_nlb) on how to find the `ingress_subdomain` and setting up DNS

If you have create a VPC load balancer, run this command

```
ibmcloud ks nlb-dns replace --cluster <cluster> --nlb-subdomain <Ingress_subdomain> --lb-host <VPC_lb_hostname>
```

You can find the complete VPC cluster [documentation here](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/containers?topic=containers-ingress-user_managed#user_managed_vpc)